# Jetpack Compose progress indicator

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, progress-bar, okhttp, coil, diskcache

My code downloads several images from the cloud to the cache at the same time without showing them on the screen, the code works fine

```kotlin
val loaderlistener = object : progressRespondBody.progressListener {
                    
                    override fun Update(byteread: Long, contentLength: Long, done: Boolean) {
                        100 * byteread / contentLength != (100).toLong()

                        Log.i("progressListener_image", "done: ${100 * byteread / contentLength}");
                    }
                }

                val mediaPathList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
                
                val imageloader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
                    .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
                    .crossfade(true)
                    .allowHardware(false)
                    .okHttpClient {
                        OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                            .addInterceptor(Interceptor { chain ->
                                val orginalres = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                                orginalres.newBuilder()
                                    .body(progressRespondBody(orginalres.body!!,loaderlistener))
                                    .build()
                            })
                            .build()
                    }
                    .diskCache {
                        if (save_local_external) {
                            path =              
                   context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)!!.path.toPath()
                            DiskCache.Builder()
                                .maxSizePercent(0.4)
                                .directory(path)
                                .build()
                        } else {
                            DiskCache.Builder()
                                .maxSizePercent(0.1)
                                .directory(path)
                                .build()
                        }
                    }
                     .build()

                  imagelist?.forEach { imageUrl ->
                    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                        .data(imageUrl)
                        .crossfade(true)
                        .build()
                     imageloader.enqueue(request)

                    imagelist.take(3).forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
                    val mediaPath =  
                   imageloader.diskCache?.openSnapshot(MemoryCache.Key(imagelist[index]).key)?.data.toString()
                        mediaPathList.add(mediaPath)
                    }                    
                }
```

I want the user to show the download progress and after downloading the download window is closed
when I do this, the download process repeats endlessly and throws an error
How do I get this?

```kotlin
val progressState = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
                val loaderlistener = remember {
                    object : progressRespondBody.progressListener {
                        override fun Update(byteread: Long, contentLength: Long, done: Boolean) {
                            if (contentLength != (100).toLong()) {
                                val newProgress = 100 * byteread / contentLength
                                progressState.value = newProgress.toFloat()

                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
```

```kotlin
val mediaPathList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

                val imageloader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
                    .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
                    .crossfade(true)
                    .allowHardware(false)
                    .okHttpClient {
                        OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                            .addInterceptor(Interceptor { chain ->
                                val orginalres = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                                orginalres.newBuilder()
                                    .body(progressRespondBody(orginalres.body!!,loaderlistener))
                                    .build()
                            })
                            .build()
                    }
                    .diskCache {
                        if (save_local_external) {
                            path =
                                context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)!!.path.toPath()
                            DiskCache.Builder()
                                .maxSizePercent(0.4)
                                .directory(path)
                                .build()
                        } else {
                            DiskCache.Builder()
                                .maxSizePercent(0.1)
                                .directory(path)
                                .build()
                        }
                    }
                    .build()
```

```kotlin
imagelist?.forEach { imageUrl ->
                    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                        .data(imageUrl)
                        .crossfade(true)
                        .build()
                    imageloader.enqueue(request)

                    imagelist.take(3).forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
                        val mediaPath = imageloader.diskCache?.openSnapshot(MemoryCache.Key(imagelist[index]).key)?.data.toString()
                        mediaPathList.add(mediaPath)
                    }
                    if (clear){
                        imageloader.diskCache?.clear()
                    }
                }
```

```kotlin
LinearProgressIndicator(
                   progress = progressState.value,
                   modifier = Modifier
                      .fillMaxWidth()
                      .height(16.dp)
             )
```

Comment: the problem is solved. when I send the `val imageloader = remember{ ImageLoader.Builder(context)...}` inside remember, everything works as it should